# On mouse move from top to bottom the border of td disappears in Edge(V-91). It reappears if you scroll or move mouse from bottom to top of the table

Tags: html-table, border, microsoft-edge, mouseout

The minimal code is given below. Note that -

1. I need 1px border(I think that means need border-collapse).
2. Also transition and background-color change cannot be compromised.
3. CSS only solution.

Am doing wrong or would you have a fix/alternate, or its a bug. Please help me out. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    #wrap-div{display:flex;}
    #com_table{width:800px; border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0px; margin:50px auto;text-align:center}
    th, td{border:1px solid #3AC;}
    #com_table > tbody > tr:hover{color:#fff; background-color:#aaa; transition:all .25s linear;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrap-div">
        <table id="com_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Total Amt</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>24/05/2021</td>
                    <td>NEW</td>
                    <td>900.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>24/05/2021</td>
                    <td>CONFIRMED</td>
                    <td>900.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>28/05/2021</td>
                    <td>CONFIRMED</td>
                    <td>850.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>28/05/2021</td>
                    <td>CONFIRMED</td>
                    <td>1845.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>15/05/2021</td>
                    <td>SETTLED</td>
                    <td>4221.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>17/05/2021</td>
                    <td>SETTLED</td>
                    <td>1549.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>17/05/2021</td>
                    <td>SETTLED</td>
                    <td>250.00</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>18/05/2021</td>
                    <td>SETTLED</td>
                    <td>1249.00</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made some tests, and I found that the problem only occurs when the screen resolution is 1600*900 with Edge 91.0.864.41 on one computer. In other computers, it works well. In addition, I also tested in [Edge Canary](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/canary) and there is no issue on all computers, so I think the issue will be fixed in a future version of Edge. You can wait for the release of the new Edge version.

Comment: @YuZhou thanks for your response. My screen resolution is 1366 X 768. However, I think you are right.